# Measure of a compact with no induced interior inside a compact with no interior.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $F_{1}$ is a bounded closed set in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$  ($m\geq 1$) with no interior. Suppose  $F_{2}\subset F_{1}$ is also closed set with no interior in the induced topology of $F_{1}$. Can we say that $F_{2}$ is a null set for the $m$-dimensional Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $K\subset [0,1]$ be a fat Cantor set, let $F_1=K\times [0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $F_2=K\times K$.  Then $F_1$ is closed with empty interior in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $F_2$ is closed with empty interior in $F_1$ but $F_2$ has positive measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

More generally, if $F_1\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ is any subset of positive measure, then there exists a subset $F_2\subset F_1$ which is closed and empty interior in $F_1$ and has positive measure.  To construct $F_2$, let $\{q_n\}$ be a countable dense subset of $F_1$, and choose an open ball around each $q_n$ such that the sum of the measures of all the balls is less than the measure of $F_1$.  Then if $F_2$ is $F_1$ with these balls removed, $F_2$ still has positive measure but is closed and has empty interior in $F_1$.